# Автоматическое выполнение скриптов в зависимости от положения ползунка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Подскажите не очень опытному верстальщику. С помощью `jQuery` создал блок с ползунком. Всё работает замечательно. В блоке у меня список областей России. Рядом карта России с этими областями. Нажимаешь на область на карте она подсвечивается. Это я реализовал нехитрой командой:

```
$("#img3").click(function(){
    $("#obl2, #obl4, #obl5, #obl6, #obl7, #obl8").hide();
    $("#obl3").fadeIn();
});
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы при скролле ползунка автоматически отрабатывалось событие. Например, когда ползунок достигает определенного положения возле области -  на карте должна появляться метка. Пробовал условия ставить, чтобы сработал скрипт, но ничего не получалось. Например, так:

```
if ($(".ui-slider .ui-slider-handle").css("left")=="50%"){
   $("#obl8").show();
}
```

Comment: Нужно использовать событие [`onchange`](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change)

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что речь идет о `<input type="range"/>`?

Comment: Нет, я не использовал тэг input. Сначала было обрадовался простому созданию ползунка <input type="range" min="0" max="100"> и ву а ля. Но не понял как мне с помощью него пролистывать содержание блока и поэтому использовал плагин из jquery, там я так понимаю он работает как слайдер

Comment: можете пример показать на jsfiddle например?